# Tomcat 8.x not loading custom jar from 'lib' folder

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

**Background**-I am trying to deploy a custom jar to the Tomcat 8.x lib("${catalina.home}/lib") folder. Per Tomcat documentation, it should be picked up when the server starts(via common classloader), and classes(from the jar) are made available to Tomcat and other apps deployed on it. However, I have an app deployed on Tomcat which is looking for the classes from this jar, but it fails with NoClassDef found error.

**What I have done so far**- I have tried to look at the classes deployed by using -verbose:class but am unable to find the class(es) from the jar. It appears that tomcat ignored the custom jar(yes- I understand all the classes are not loaded at the startup rather they can be 'found' using delegation pattern at runtime). To test that tomcat is working per documentation ie autoload from 'lib' folder, I threw in the ojdbc.jar in the same lib folder. Voila- I could see it loading some classes from the ojdbc jar(at this stage,my code doesn't need ojdbc.jar or classes from it).

**Need help** -- I am unable to understand why tomcat is ignoring my custom jar, while it deploys ojdbc.jar(at a theoretical level it is also custom as it is not bundled with tomcat) ?

Comment: Hello, it's a good practice to provide some visual info (pictures of errors, code, and others). In that way, we can help better.

Comment: "pictures of errors" - Quick note: Please don't post _pictures_ of text (errors, code, data, etc) - post the text itself, formatted for readability. Stack Overflow has various [code formatting options](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). (@L.Papadopoulos) Apart from that, I agree completely that your question is more likely to be answered if you can provide some more specific details.

Comment: Having said that, it is more typical for a Tomcat web application's JARs to be placed in that application's `/WEB-INF/lib` directory, rather than in `CATALINA_HOME/lib` or `CATALINA_BASE/lib`. JDBC drivers are a somewhat different beast, because of SPI - maybe OJDBC is likewise different. More info [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html). And [here for JDBC](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html). **Question**: Is your JAR found if you place it in the application's `/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: Yes, but specifically for 'errors', it's not code, so isnt it better to just post pictures of them?

Comment: I understand your point @L.Papadopoulos - and there is no absolute rule for this, but I try to follow the [guidance provided here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) - and I try to only use pictures if there is no better way. (With apologies to sfjmx for the digression from their question!)